# Superfish z-index issue for IE 7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, superfish

I cannot seem to fix the z-index issue with IE7 for superfish.

[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hybmg57/zSTum/)

I just need menu showing up on top of background font not the other way round basically.

I've tried putting in z-index on sh-menu classes and li's but nothing seems to work.

Is there something I need to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only two places I set a z-index value in superfish are:

```
.sf-menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999; /* Ensure drop-down menus are always on top */
}

.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;    /* Ensures that the drop down is always directly below the nav bar */
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `position: absolute` in this css rule `.sf-menu li.sfHover ul`

http://jsfiddle.net/zSTum/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add the `z-index` attribute to your `.menu` class instead.

e.g.

```
.menu {
  z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: @JohnKim tested it on a clean install of IE7 on a virtual PC and you're right, it did not work, hmm, tested under the MultipleIE install app and it worked there. I'll do some more testing and check back.

Comment: @JohnKim by the way, just checked the support for canvas in IE8 and below and there doesn't seem to be any, http://caniuse.com/canvas

Comment: there is conditional CSS in place so if it's IE canvas doesn't get triggered. Canvas is created by Cufon FYI